# Solutions to Mordell's equation $x^2 = y^3 + 8$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, mordell-curves

It seems to be known that all the integral solutions to this equation are (0, -2) ($\pm$ 3, 1), ($\pm$ 4, 2), ($\pm$ 312, 46).  Yet I can't seem to find any proofs that these are all the solutions.

Using the (semi)-unique factorization in $Z[\sqrt{8}]$, we get
$x + \sqrt{8} = \alpha \omega (a + b\sqrt{8})^3$,  where $a, b$ are relatively prime integers, $a$ is odd,  $\omega \in \{1, 3 + \sqrt{8}, 3 - \sqrt{8} \}$ and $\alpha \in \{ \sqrt{8}, 4 + \sqrt{8}, 1\}$.   I was able to take care of the case $\omega = 1$ easily,  but have had problems with the other two cases;   the algebra gets tricky and messy.

I've also tried playing with the factorization $y^3 + 8 = (y+2)(y^2 - 2y + 4)$ and have concluded that the only primes that divide both factors on the right hand side are 2 and 3,  but that's it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is it written that these are all the integer solutions?

Comment: in Mordell's book   he finishes these arguments by appealing to binary cubic  forms.  These methods were explored by Nagell and by Ljunggren; these tend to give  four or five solutions to the original problem.

Comment: @WillJagy: Are you saying it is in Mordell's book?

Comment: @markvs  not as such. There are tables for Mordell curves;  see first page (out of 4000 or so)  at https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~bennett/0-10%5E6n.pdf

Comment: @markvs See also [the LMFDB database](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/576/e/4). No explanations, but wealth of information.

Comment: The notes by [K. Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/mordelleqn1.pdf) give a lot of examples and ideas.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2871646/solution-to-mordells-equation-y2-x34), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1199967/elementary-solution-to-the-mordell-equation-y2-x39), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1122481/the-diophantine-equation-y2-x37-has-no-solutions) and many more.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Conrad's notes contain many cases but the case $k=8$ is not there. Clearly that case is harder than what is in his notes.

Comment: @WillJagy: Yes, this list contains the equation with $k=8$.

Comment: @markvs  I know, but also it seems tiring to see each time a new question for $y^2=x^3+k$ and some new integer $k$. This site has more than twenty posts on it already. It is interesting to see some new cases, yes, but eventually the database seems the better choice.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Yes, it is annoying. One way to deal with it is to find a paper (by Bennett) where all these cases are considered, post a general question, answer it, and then close every new such question as a duplicate.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: I posted an answer to this question which makes it possible to close all future questions about Mordell equations as duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of this answer is to make it possible to view every future question about Mordell equation $y^2=x^3+n$ a duplicate. See  J. Gebel, A. Petho and H. G. Zimmer, ‘On Mordell’s equations’, Compos. Math. 110 (1998) no. 3,
335–367 where integral solutions of all such equations are found for $n<10^4$.

Here is a quote  from [this article by Bennett](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Ebennett/BeGh-LMSJCM-2015.pdf):

> There are alternative approaches for finding the integral points on a given model of an
> elliptic curve. The most commonly used currently proceeds via appeal to lower bounds for
> linear forms in elliptic logarithms, the idea for which dates back to work of Lang [27] and
> Zagier [38] (though the bounds required to make such arguments explicit are found in work
> of David and of Hirata-Kohno; see, for example, [6]). Using these bounds, Gebel et al. [16],
> Smart [33] and Stroeker and Tzanakis [34] obtained, independently, a ‘practical’ method to
> find integral points on elliptic curves. Applying this method, in 1998, Gebel et al. [17] solved
> equation (1.1) for all integers $|k| < 10^4$ and partially extended the computation to $|k| < 10^5$
> .

Comment: @Mike: Yes, it will. According to a new rule, every question Q1 for which there is a question Q2 having an answer solving Q1 is considered a duplicate of Q2 and should be closed. Moreover, if somebody posts a question about $y^2=x^3+n$ with $n>10^4$, we should close it because the paper by Gebel et al. contains a procedure to solve every such equation.

Comment: Thank you for your help.   Why was aware some of these papers,  I was just wondering if there was a more elementary solution for this particular case that undergraduate math students could understand.

Comment: @TomBlackford: Note one solution $(\pm 312, 46)$. This indicates that a completely elementary solution does not exist.